# Game theory books on learning e.g. Fictitious play

Tags: game-theory

I'm looking for some text books on learning in game theory. So far I only found

> The Theory of Learning in Games

by Fudenberg and Levine. Are there others you can recommend?

Answer (score 3):

Two I would recommend in addition are:

- Strategic Learning and its Limits. H. Peyton Young
- Prediction, Learning, and Games. Nicolo Cesa-Bianchi and Gabor Lugosi